# Can I securely keep the user logged into my local application AND use the password as a decryption key?

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords

I'm somewhat new to data encryption/safety, but I already read about basic concepts like hashing passwords, encrypting files, etc. If possible, please ELI5 - thanks in advance.

Background: my application interacts with a third party (Twitch) using an OAuth key for IRC as well as a Client ID. Both of these can be used to effectively access the application's Twitch account and do anything with it. The keys are sent as plaintext whenever the application establishes a connection with the Twitch servers (which I can't do anything about and it's not really that huge of a problem). My main security concern is about someone getting access to the user's computer and stealing the keys from there.

**I'd like to securely store these on the disk** so that the user doesn't have to log into Twitch every time they open the application (to retrieve the keys). To do this, **my best solution so far was to encrypt the file containing them**. The obvious way to do this would be to **require a password when the application starts**, then use a stored hash+salt to check that password, and **use the password (or its hash with a different salt) as a key to decrypt the file**.

As said before, I'm new to data protection, so there might be a much better way to do this. Please do suggest one if there is one. However, as for this...

**If *possible*, I'd also like to not have the user enter their password every time they open the application** - simply for user convenience. Prompting the password once per user session (or once every time the computer is restarted) seems reasonable.

**I thought about doing this by storing something in RAM, or perhaps by storing some kind of hash as a temporary file.** However, I haven't been able to come to an actual conclusion yet. Maybe I'm asking for too much. Nevertheless, is there an actual, decent way to implement this? If not, is prompting for a password on every application startup a better idea than going about storing those Twitch keys securely in some other way?

If it matters - for my specific case, I'm using Python 3.7, and I aim to make my application cross-platform (as long as the system supports Python).

Comment: Twitch supports [OpenID](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/), and the dev page have helpful sample code. You should start there.

Comment: @ThoriumBR: OIDC isn't openid, it's oauth with features borrowed from openid. And even if you use it, you still have to store a cookie/token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be cross-platform, consider using a Python module which provides access to various platforms' **existing** built-in "keyring" systems. A popular one is called [python-keyring](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/).

In all platforms which have a keyring, it is stored encrypted with the user's login password and unlocked in RAM while the user is logged in.

(This isn't super-secure, as technically other programs can also request the same password from the OS... but practically all other "store something in RAM" options would have the same problem, so it's not a downgrade.)

Comment: I actually had no idea that Windows had its own implementation of keyrings - that's what I was actually thinking about before asking this question, I guess I should've researched more. This solution works fine for my case... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes – although the python-keyring page implies it's something UWP-specific, but in reality it uses the same ['credential' API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincred/) that has existed since Windows XP. (I checked, it imports win32cred from PyWin32.)